# Selenium Python: How to extract text within a href element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am looking for a way to extract/print text which is located within a href element.

Snapshot of the HTML:
[image: snapshot of HTML]

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//div[contains(@class, "style1")]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "style1")]').text
```

Error massage: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Many more trials to locate this "0" without success. The number will change when some open 'tickets' appear in the system.

How this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

if you print this, it should return the value `0`

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "style1")]/a'))).text)
```

---

You need to change this from

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "style1")]').text
```

to

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "style1")]/a').text)
```

You need to import this library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your code, but still get this error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: @Paulina, Sorry I mistake. Try now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: now i get: "TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: @Paulina, Just copy exact what I have posted.  if you don't want to print this just use this line `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "style1")]/a')))` I am sure you have missed one parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. The `untill()` method accepts a *`tuple`*. Hence you see the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Moreover the text *`0`* is within the descendant `<a>` of the `<div>`.

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code will be:

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'style1')]/a"))).text)
  ```
- Using *`get_attribute()`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'style1')]/a"))).get_attribute('textContent'))
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative considering thw *`href`* attribute of the `<a>` tag you can use:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style1']/a[starts-with(@href, '/scp/endeavour/deviationDetailsPortlet')]"))).text)
```

Comment: both lines suggested in 'Solution' shows Syntax error (pointing out s in "style1") - don't know why there. Alternative code give Timeout error.

Comment: 1) _both lines suggested in 'Solution' shows Syntax error (pointing out s in "style1")_: my bad, corrected the bug. 2) _Alternative code give Timeout error_": corrected now